# Where is the setting for highlighting unused variables and constants in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am working in a C# project where this has been turned off.

I can't find out how to turn it on again.

It's pretty hard to google as it's default behavior, and no sane person would turn it off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Did you perhaps change your compiler warning level?

Unused variables should have the warning of [CS0168](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0168?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0168)).  If you look at that page, the title is "Compiler Warning (**level 3**) CS0168".

In solution explorer, right click your project and go to Build and check your Warning Level:

[image: Warning Level]

If you set it to anything lower than three, then the CS0168 warnings will never be shown.  Also, just below the drop down is a suppress warnings text box.  Make sure you don't have `CS0168` in that text box.

###### Are you using an .editorconfig file?

If you are using an .editorconfig file, you may have suppressed this particular warning.  Removing that suppression should resolve this as well.  It would look something like this in your .editorconfig file:

```
[*.cs]

# CS0168: Variable is declared but never used
dotnet_diagnostic.CS0168.severity = none
```

Comment: Okay why does my screen look entirely different in VS2022? I don't see the "define debug / trace" checkboxes only "general -> conditional compilation symbols"

Comment: @Enrico I'm not entirely sure.  Make sure you are right clicking on the **project** and not the solution.  What you see here might depend on the type of project as well, but I am not positive.  I think I might have read that older projects (ones created in older versions of Visual Studio) may not have the same options available to them.  I captured the screenshot by using a ASP.NET Web API project.  Perhaps test out a few dummy projects of varying types to see what options are present here.  This was also performed on Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise edition (preview version).

Comment: My level is set to 4.  I have no warning codes suppressed.  Nothing about it in .editorconfig file.  But VS is still not showing the warnings to me.  I can't tell what I'm missing.