# Missing "Define debug and define trace constant" checkbox in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm missing two checkboxes for defining constants in my properties screen. Am I missing something?
[image]

It should look like this

[image]

I'm using a Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web project in net6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere along the way, Visual Studio streamlined these options to what you are seeing instead of what you are *expecting* to see.  Actually, I don't think this is a Visual Studio-specific change, but rather it depends on what kind of project and what SDK you are using - those being:

- .NET Framework
- .NET (.NET Core)

I am guessing you are coming from [one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173096/where-is-the-setting-for-highlighting-unused-variables-and-constants-in-visual-s/72188879?noredirect=1#comment128027892_72188879), which sparked you to ask this question.  In my post, that screenshot is from a **.NET Framework project**.  I should have probably been slightly more specific in my [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173096/where-is-the-setting-for-highlighting-unused-variables-and-constants-in-visual-s/72188879?noredirect=1#comment128030488_72188879) to you. In your project, you are clearly using .NET 6 (as you mentioned above).  Because of that, your properties menu looks way different.  This is the streamlining I am talking about.

So where are your checkboxes for defining DEBUG and TRACE constants? They are gone! However, you are looking right at the control that replaced them - or rather, you are looking at how these controls work now.  Essentially, the `$(DefineConstants)` replaces these checkboxes, and you can specify additional constants in the same textbox, separating each by a semicolon.  If you hover over the "Conditional compilation symbols" controls and click the gear icon, you can toggle it to vary by configuration, which I think is more clear and useful to do:

[image: constants]

Then, if you wish to add custom constants, simply add them to the configurations.  In the below screenshot, I added an `ONLY_DEBUG` to the Debug configuration, and an `ONLY_Release` in the Release configuration:

[image: custom constants]

In the code, you can use them as so:

[image: code example]

Microsoft Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#defineconstants).