Visual Studio C# - how to fade out unused variables?
Is it possible to fade out unused variables (similar to using statements).
I don't want to throw errors or warnings for unused variables while I'm sketching out my classes, but the visual cue that it's not being used would help dramatically in understanding what is going on.

This should happen with the default settings in Visual Studio. What year and edition are you using (e.g. 2019 Community, 2022 Enterprise, etc.)?

2022 - maybe a month old version. It is a very old project though - maybe there are some project settings or editorconfig why this is not working. Thanks, I'll try to investigate further.

Do you know if this is like old "classic" behaviour or that this is related to code analyzers?

I'm not sure I ever saw a faded out variable, I believe that only happens to unreachable code. But it does underline unused variables with a blue squiggly line and recommends deleting them.

See if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173096/where-is-the-setting-for-highlighting-unused-variables-and-constants-in-visual-s/72188879#72188879 It may be related to compiler warning level.

FWIW, it looks like this or a very similar issue is plaguing lots of users in VS 2022: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Fading-of-unused-variables-not-working/10519732#T-N10552227 Maybe a feature that worked OK in 2019 but in 2022 it's buggy? Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/unused-values-parameters?view=vs-2022 "unused value assignments" should definitely be faded out, not just unreachable code.

As @TylerH said in the comments, this problem bothers many users in VS 2022, and many users have reported this problem to the VS developer community. I believe that the relevant team is currently optimizing this problem, and when enough users report this problem, the team will prioritize it.
In addition, after my test, if you change the warning level, such as changing the warning level to 2, the warning of level 3 for unused variables will disappear, but the wavy line under the unused variables will also disappear. If you accept this suggestion, you can refer to this link.
